# Data migration when external Id is not unique on the detail object

Tags: data-loader, migration, externalid

We are migrating records from one org to another org and I ran into this scenario.

**Background**:

1. We have two objects with master detail relation between them and API names are `Master__c` and `Detail__c`
2. On each object, we have External Id column named `External_Id__c` to make the data migration easier when moving between environments.
3. Here is the simple schema of the data.

   [image]
4. We have two records in `Master__c` object and 4 records(two records corresponding to each record in master) in `Detail__c` object.

**Data migration**:

1. It is straight forward that first we should move `Master__c` records and then `Detail__c` records.
2. First, I loaded Master__c records by selecting Upsert Operation in Dataloader and selecting column `External_Id__c` as external Id and it went fine.

**Question**:

Can I migrate Detail__c records using Upsert operation given that `Detail__c.External_Id__c` values are not unique?

I was told by the person who designed that he chose to populate the `Detail__c.External_Id__c` field to match with its parent record `MasterId__r.External_Id__c` and mentioned that there are some tools to handle this kind of data when moving between environments. Can someone explain me on how to do this?

**Note**: I am not looking for crazy vlookup operation.

Comment: if I recall, in Data Loader, you choose which column in the CSV corresponds to the field representing the master; the External_ID__c column in Detail__c should be unique ids for the detail records in case they are the target of some other sobject's lookup

Comment: @cropredy I was able to resolve parent object relation by mapping `Master__r.External_Id__c`. The only thing is there are duplicates for `Detail__c.External_Id__c` and it is causing issues with Upsert operation in Dataloader. I am not sure if this data setup is even correct for upsert operation. I could not get hold of the person who designed this also I am not sure if this setup is correct. wanted to check with experts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is the CSV for the `Detail__c`

You have two columns

- `External_ID__c` : This needs to be either null or unique for each detail record
- `Master__r.External_Id__c` : This should be the external ID of records in `Master__c`. You will use Data Loader to associate this column to the Master__c.External_Id__c field

When migrating, if Detail__c is never the parent of any other object being migrated, then Detail__c.External_ID__c can be null. But if it will be the parent of some other object, say `Foo__c` that has a lookup to `Detail__c`, then these Detail__c will need to have unique `External_ID__c`

Alternatively, if `Detail__c` is never the parent of any other object being migrated, just don;t bother to map that column in the Data Loader